# Vuejs - Can I access environment variables through chrome inspector?

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a possibility to access environment variables through Chrome inspector?

Thank you

Comment: do you mean your vue.js variables defined in `data`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, no environment variables are exposed to the compiled client-side application.

But you can selectively include variables to your code by hand, e.g. inside HTML comments or console log outputs.

See also [Vue CLI: Using Env Variables in Client-side Code](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code):

> You can access env variables in your application code:
>
> `console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET)`
>
> During build, `process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET` will be replaced by the corresponding value. In the case of `VUE_APP_SECRET=secret`, it will be replaced by "secret".